# remind vs remind of

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "remind" and "remind of" ?

```
I remind him of the meeting which is going to be held tomorrow.

I remind him the meeting to be held tomorrow.
```

Comment: There will be no difference in meaning if you  put "is" after meeting  in the second sentence. The use of "that" after him is optional.  The sentence will also  be 0K if you just put "of" after him.

Answer (score 4):

There are several different ways we can go about expressing the idea in your example sentences:

- remind + someone + of + noun (usually an event, obligation, etc.)

> I **reminded him of the meeting** tomorrow.
>   
>   You have to be careful with that construction because it is also used to express that A has some characteristic that makes you think of B (e.g. My son **reminds me of** my father.).

- remind + someone + that-clause

  > I **reminded him that** there is a meeting tomorrow.
- remind + someone + infinitive clause

  > I **reminded him to attend** the meeting tomorrow.

As to the difference between *remind* and *remind of* as you used them in your examples, *of* is required to make the sentence grammatically correct. We need that *of* preposition to be included if our sentence has an object (the meeting) following the person being reminded (him).